# Devise + Rails-API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-api

So, I'm starting an API from a new rails-api project.
I would like to use Devise for all the authentication stuff. I already learned a lot from my recent googling-sessions. I have a working SessionsController, however I noticed with the RegisterController that I certainly missed something about the duo Rails-API+Devise.

I still get the following error :

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method 'flash' for #    <RegistrationsController:0x007ff6022b44b8>)`
```

From a pure API perspective should I keep working with Devise flash messages since I don't want to render views? I didn't included `ActionDispatch::Flash` based on the principe that I'll just render JSON. So, is there a way to properly deal with that case?

Thank you.

Comment: I wrote [this blog post about using Rails 4 + Rails-API + devise](http://www.emilsoman.com/blog/2013/05/18/building-a-tested/). You may find it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather suggest to send messages in json instead of having flash[:messages]. If you are not dealing with views then go for json, flash is not required.

Something like:

```
      render :json => {:message => "message", :data => data}
```