# Rails 5 API override devise SessionsController sign out error

Tags: devise, rails-routing, rails-api

I had created a rails 5 api project
and use

```
Devise gem 4.1.0
Ruby 2.3.0
Rails 5.0.0.rc1
```

I ran command to override SessionsController

```
rails generate devise:controllers users
```

My Custom SessionsController is

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
# before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    super
  end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    super
  end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_in_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
  # end
end
```

I got error when call path to sign_out

```
127.0.0.1:3000/users/sign_out
```

The error is

```
"status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "#<NameError: undefined local variable or method `flash' for #<Users::SessionsController:0x00000003d2e8f0>>",
  "traces": {
    "Application Trace": [],
    "Framework Trace": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "trace": "devise (4.1.1) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:157:in `set_flash_message'"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "trace": "devise (4.1.1) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:164:in `set_flash_message!'"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "trace": "devise (4.1.1) app/controller
```

s/devise/sessions_controller.rb:61:in `verify_signed_out_user'"
      },

My current routes in routes.rb

```
devise_for :users,
             controllers: {
                sessions: 'users/sessions',
                registrations: 'users/registrations'
             }
```

I debugged but the path didn't route to app/controller/users/SessionsController
How can i route that path

Comment: Maybe this question will help you:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292137/devise-rails-api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292137/devise-rails-api)

Comment: Thanks @graffzon
I can not override destroy method in any controllers inherited from Devise::[Controller name]Controller. So i remove inheritance from the Devise controllers. It worked well for me

Answer (score 1):

The destroy needs to be altered to perform on a get request

proceed to config/enitializers/devise.rb and on line 239 change

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

to

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```